# convert csv number format to real number

Tags: php, csv

when parsing a CSV file, how would I transform the scientific notation numbers into real numbers?

For example in a column I have : 
4,41431E+13
I think it's real value is : 44143100000000

I have tried using [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) but it doesn't convert.

Thanks

Comment: Is it `4,41431E+13` in the csv file if you view it using a text editor? Or only when you open it in MS Excel?

Answer (score 3):

The main issue is that the scientific notation shown in your sample is using a comma as decimal separator, so you first have to switch your locale to a locale that uses a comma (I use french in the example)

```
<?php
// switch the locale to one using , as decimal separator
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'fr_FR');
// intermediate step via float as intval doesn't seem to like the comma
$big_float = floatval("4,41431E+13");
// and finally to integer
$big_integer = intval($big_float);
```

Now $big_integer will correctly contain the integer value 44143100000000

Answer (score -2):

It's too late. Excel has already messed up the formatting. If you view the CSV in Notepad you'll see that this is the case.